# Is there a default polymorphic unit type haskell

Tags: haskell

in Haskell there is a default unit type, namely (). I'm looking for a polymorphic one (preferably in Hackage), for instance:

```
data PUT a = PUT
```

or perhaps a polymorphic zero type:

```
data PZT a = PZT (PZT a)
```

So yes, I could write one myself, by either of the above statements. I'm looking for one in hackage.

The reason I need it, is because I have a class with multiple type parameters, which contains a function that does not use one of them:

```
class MyClass a b where
  someFunction :: a
  -- and some other functions
```

when using this function "someFunction", GHC cannot find the right instance, so I changed my definition:

```
class MyClass a b where
  someFunction :: (PUT b) -> a
```

Now when I call someFunction, I can use (PUT::SomeType) as its first argument, and Haskell can derive which instance I meant. Every time I use this trick, I write a new polymorphic unit type (it's just one line of codes), which gives me a bit of extra work when combining different libraries (because preferably, I'd use the same constructor everywhere).
I'm sure that other people ran into this problem, so maybe one of them put a solution in hackage (ghc's packet manager)? I'd like to import it. Am I searching for the wrong thing, or does it not exist in hackage?

Comment: I'm confused by the meaning of "polymorphic zero type". I would have expected it to mean, a type which is uninhabited except for undefined, like Void is. But I can construct a value of your PZT type, via `let p = PZT p`, and can pattern-match on it successfully, so either I misunderstand what you mean by PZT, or your PZT isn't one. You could build a polymorphic Void more simply, of course: `data Avoid a` is uninhabited.

Comment: Sure you don't need a funDep there?  Helps with inference for MPTCs.

Comment: It turns out you don't really need such a type. The following also works:

`class MyClass a b where
  someFunction :: (f b) -> a`

Note that, since there is no information about f (it is not Applicative or anything) this means there is no way to get to the b, which is precisely what I needed.

Comment: @Sebastiaan Yes, that's good practice. Usages of [`Data.Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Proxy.html) commonly treat it polymorphically (`proxy a -> b` instead of `Proxy a -> b`), so you can substitute the functor of your choice if you have one around, rather than being forced to write `Proxy :: Proxy MyType` and turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`. This is how the [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) API works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is usually called `Proxy`. Since base-4.7, it is available in [Data.Proxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Proxy.html)

A similar thing, which is available in base since longer than `Proxy`, is [`Const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:Const), e.g. you can use `Const ()`.

Comment: Also note the common idiom of expressing the type of `someFunction` not as `Proxy b -> a` but as `proxy b -> a` (note capitalization) so as not to require `Proxy` itself.